# Where to add WHERE clause in Inner Join?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query and I need to add a where clause (`WHERE order_number = 1`) on my first query, but it's not working.

```
SELECT 
    last_name,
    first_name,
    total,
    pickup_date,
    MPU.salary,
    MTU.materials,
    OFU.otherfee
FROM
    finished AS FD
        INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
        order_number, (SUM(salary * hours_worked)) AS 'salary'
    FROM
        manpower_used
    GROUP BY order_number) AS MPU ON FD.order_number = MPU.order_number
        INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
        order_number, (SUM(qty * price)) AS 'materials'
    FROM
        materials_used
    GROUP BY order_number) AS MTU ON FD.order_number = MTU.order_number
        INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
        order_number,
            (SUM(overtime_fee + stair_fee + toll_fee)) AS 'otherfee'
    FROM
        other_fees
    GROUP BY order_number) AS OFU ON FD.order_number = OFU.order_number
```

Thank you!

Comment: At the end `..Where fd.order_number = 1` or in any `ON` condition `FD.order_number = MPU.order_number and fd.order_number = 1`

Comment: at it at the end of your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the very end.

```
SELECT 
    last_name,
    first_name,
    total,
    pickup_date,
    MPU.salary,
    MTU.materials,
    OFU.otherfee
FROM
    finished AS FD
        INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
        order_number, (SUM(salary * hours_worked)) AS 'salary'
    FROM
        manpower_used
    GROUP BY order_number) AS MPU ON FD.order_number = MPU.order_number
        INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
        order_number, (SUM(qty * price)) AS 'materials'
    FROM
        materials_used
    GROUP BY order_number) AS MTU ON FD.order_number = MTU.order_number
        INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
        order_number,
            (SUM(overtime_fee + stair_fee + toll_fee)) AS 'otherfee'
    FROM
        other_fees
    GROUP BY order_number) AS OFU ON FD.order_number = OFU.order_number
    Where FD.order_number = 1   -- here
```

For comparing date (say pickup_date) for year and month, you can add another filter like so:

```
AND date_format(pickup_date,'%m-%Y') = date_format(curdate(),'%m-%Y')
```

Comment: Thank you sir last question, how to retrieve the datas this month, and this year only?

Comment: @Aaron Updated in the answer

Answer (score 0):

Before the group by as a `Where` clause if it's on a field not aggregated,

```
Select [stuff]
From [tables and joins]
Where [Filter predicates]
group by [grouping expressions]
```

like:

```
Select s.storeId, count(*)
from stores s join storeproducts sp 
    on sp.storeId = s.storeId
Where s.State = 'CA'
group by s.storeId
```

after the group by as `Having` clause if it involves an aggregate function

```
Select [stuff]
From [tables and joins]
group by [grouping expressions]
Having [filter predicates on aggregate expressions]
```

like:

```
Select s.storeId, count(*)
from stores s join storeproducts sp 
    on sp.storeId = s.storeId
group by s.storeId
having count(*) > 12
```

in your case, there is no `group by` in outer query, so at the end as a `where` clause

```
SELECT last_name, first_name, total,
   pickup_date, MPU.salary, MTU.materials, OFU.otherfee
FROM finished f
    JOIN (SELECT order_number, 
            (SUM(salary * hours_worked)) 'salary'
          FROM manpower_used
          GROUP BY order_number) n
       ON n.order_number = f.order_number
    JOIN (SELECT order_number, SUM(qty * price) 'materials'
          FROM materials_used 
          GROUP BY order_number) t
       ON t.order_number = f.order_number
    JOIN (SELECT order_number, 
            SUM(overtime_fee + stair_fee + toll_fee) 'otherfee'
          FROM other_fees
          GROUP BY order_number) o 
       ON o.order_number = f.order_number
Where f.order_number = 1   -- here
```

Answer (score -2):

You have used aggregate function in your query , that is why WHERE won't work. you have to use HAVING keyword instead of WHERE . Try using HAVING and i hope it will work for you.

Comment: Having is important only if you want a filter condition after a Group By clause, here group by is used to aggregate and then used as a table.